# Laravel - UpdateOrCreate с условием

Tags: php, laravel

```
Journal::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'schedule' => Carbon::createFromDate($request->schedule)->format('Y-m-d'),
        'type' => 1,
    ],
    ['type' => $request->type,]
);
```

Как исправить условие, чтобы вместо `'type' => 1,` выполнить проверку `type < 5`?

Comment: Вначале сделать where() а потом делать апдейт, в плане вообще вынести `'type' => 1` в целом в where а второй массив оставить не тронутым, тогда на вначале выберет записи у которых тайп меньше 5 потом или обновит их или создаст одну новую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно осуществить так:

```
Journal::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'schedule' => Carbon::createFromDate($request->schedule)->format('Y-m-d'),
        ['type', '<', 5],
    ],
    ['type' => $request->type,]
);
```